# BIRT Designer - How do I add/generate a Table of contents (TOC)?

Tags: birt

I'm using BIRT Designer v3.7 and am generating reports in PDF and MS Word formats.

I would like to add a Table of Contents report item to my report.

I presume that I need to add TOC entries as my datasets are populated, but I have no idea how to do this.

Any ideas/assistance would be most welcome.

Answer (score 7):

Table of Contents entries are generated from Report items that appear in the report output, such as Labels, Grids, Lists, Tables and so on. So the entries are not *directly* generated as the datasets are populated, but entries can be set up against data items that are displayed in reports by specifying a TOC entry against where the data item appears in the report.

To set up a TOC entry:

- Select the report item in the report layout (by clicking on it with the mouse).
- In the Property Editor's Property tab, select the Table of Contents entry and press the `fx` button to the right of the Table of Contents entry, to invoke the Expression Builder.
- You can then use the Expression Builder dialog to specify the entry to be displayed on the TOC. Press the OK button at the bottom of the Expression Builder dialog when this is entered to your satisfaction.
- When the TOC entries are set up as required, save the report and view the report output in the Web Viewer (by selecting Run > View Report > In Web Viewer from the menu) to see the new entries. (You may need to toggle the TOC display on in the web viewer.)

So for example, if you wanted to include a TOC entry as *Summary Graph* for a graph to be displayed at the end of the report, then select the graph in the design Layout view and enter the Table of Contents entry in the Property Editor's Property tab as `"Summary Graph"`. (Literal text needs to be included within double quotes.)

When a report contains groups, TOC entries should be generated for those group values automatically.

Comment: i have grouped my data according to some attributes so it is directly shown in TOC but i have not added it from any method. how can i remove the item from table of contents